# Big difference when using Relu over Tanh on a simple problem

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I was testing a toy problem, where you have as input zeros and ones, and the output is whether the number of ones is odd or even (simplicity itself). With a MLP that uses Tanh activation, I never managed to get around random guess performance (~50%)! Just completely by chance, I tried Relu (out of desperation), and...it worked perfectly (getting an accuracy of 100% most of the time).

Then, while discussing it with a friend, we wanted to see what will happen if we replace the zeros with -1 (the task stay the same, odd or even ones). To my sheer surprise, it worked with the Tanh (performance between 75~90 %). Relu still performs better.

The code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
# from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
def generate_data(batch_size, data_length=10, zeros=True):
    x = np.random.randint(0, 2, (batch_size, data_length))

    y = x.sum(axis=1) % 2
    y = y.astype(np.int16).reshape(-1)

    if not zeros: # in this case, convert the zeros to -1
        x[x==0] = -1 
    return x, y

# With ReLU, it is perfect!. With Tanh, it is shit
# clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', verbose=True, batch_size=512, activation="relu")
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', verbose=True, batch_size=512, activation="tanh")

X_train, y_train = generate_data(batch_size=10000, data_length=10, zeros=True)
X_test, y_test = generate_data(batch_size=1000, data_length=10, zeros=True)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

To get the -1 instead of zeros, just make the `zeros` parameter `False` when using `generate_data` function.

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

Edit:
Thanks to @BlackBear and @Andreas K. for there answers. So apparently using Tanh leads the neurons to saturate (the gradient is not moving). With better choice for the learning rate, or to let the network optimize for longer time, it does work. For example, with updating the classifier choices to

```
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam', verbose=True, batch_size=512, activation="tanh", max_iter=5000, learning_rate="adaptive", n_iter_no_change=100)
```

It always works!

Comment: By increasing the learning rate to `learning_rate_init=0.05` (the default is 0.001) I was able to get the perfect score of 1.0 with `tanh` and `zeros=True` (after couple of trials, until I got nice random weights initialization). So tanh also works, but in general ReLU is better and centering the inputs to [-1, 1] also can help.

Comment: Thank you for trying! You are right, changing the learning rate can help. But I am still confused about: 
1) how such a small network is sensitive to the initial weights? and what will be a good initialization policy in this case?
2) still don't understand why Relu performs better - what advantage does it provide - ?

Comment: For 2) have a look here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23493/why-relu-is-better-than-the-other-activation-functions

Answer (score 1):

It is just an issue with the optimization procedure that is not able to find good values for the weights. You can construct a network with 2^10=1024 neurons in the hidden layer, one for each input pattern, and let the output neuron respond to the neurons corresponding to inputs with even number of ones. With this procedure, you can model every boolean function.

Comment: I don't see why why would I need all this number of neurons to model such a trivial function. They activation of the neurons are not binary activation. 
In any case, I gave it a try (having a hidden layer of 1024 neurons, with the Tanh), it gave the same result, which is expected

Comment: @OSM I just gave you an informal proof that there is a network doing what you ask, which means that the problem is the optimizer (as confirmed in the comment above). If you really wish I can show you how to build such a network.

Comment: I am perfectly aware that the task is learnable, and a network does exist to solve it (well, I just showed that with the Relu activation). My question is simply about the behavior of Tanh vs Relu on such very simple task. 
The comment from @Andreas shows that the learning rate is a factor, which i didn't pay attention to before. Even though, you can still see clearly that the network in case of Tanh is very sensitive to the initial weights, while the Relu one seems to optimize the task easily. What I don't get is why? what does the Relu offer here over the Tanh?

Comment: @OSM: tanh is simply slower to train, because of saturating neurons vanishing gradients and all that. You can also reach 100% accuracy without changing the learning rate but training for a few thousands iterations.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I have just retried it again, with much larger epochs and more relaxed stopping condition, it did optimize well!